# Trivia game unavailable. Try again soon

Tags: actions-on-google

Made an action on google and tried to run on the simulator but it's showing response as:

Your trivia isn't available. Try again soon

Tried refreshing the action console. The following is the section taken from the debug section of the action console:

```
{
  "response": "Okay. Let's get the test version of my test app.It looks like The GirlyTrivia isn’t available right now. Try again soon.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "EucBS2o5ek...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAASgN...",
  "ssmlMarkList": [],
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
     {\\\"visits\\\":1,\\\"previousQuestions\\\":[2,3,8]}}}\",\"userVerificationStatus\":\"VERIFIED\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHGNFllT5DWXeBGiW-y1vsXu8_ZrxtCh5YNk_NVtoVZ2FJEPrOcdyqQMzbMvsYG0ThZVeLKOuQzOEw\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"Talk to my test app\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.CUSTOM_STAGE\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.INTERACTIVE_CANVAS\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2019-08-29T17:19:15Z\",\"userStorage\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"17sotEPMZZT_Zh41_TYbGVxyUdBRzLTltKfPVGkBgUmw\\\":{\\\"visits\\\":1,\\\"previousQuestions\\\":[2,3,8]}}}\",\"userVerificationStatus\":\"VERIFIED\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHGNFllT5DWXeBGiW-y1vsXu8_ZrxtCh5YNk_NVtoVZ2FJEPrOcdyqQMzbMvsYG0ThZVeLKOuQzOEw\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"Talk to my test app\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.CUSTOM_STAGE\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.INTERACTIVE_CANVAS\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}",
      "delegatedRequest": {
        "delegatedRequest": ""
      }
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"expectUserResponse\":false,\"finalResponse\":{\"speechResponse\":{\"textToSpeech\":\"It looks like The GirlyTrivia  isn’t available right now. Try again soon.\"}}}",

  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Okay. Let's get the test version of my test app."
        }
      },
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "It looks like The GirlyTrivia  isn’t available right now. Try again soon."
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/voice/opa/partner_icons/generic_3p_avatar.png",
    "agentStyle": {
      "primaryColor": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "borderRadius": 0,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "backgroundImageUrl": ""
    }
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": true,
  "clientOperationList": [
    {
      "operationType": 4,
      "startIndicatorPayLoad": {
        "status": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "operationType": 7,
      "exitIndicatorPayLoad": {
        "status": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "projectName": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any minimum questions required in trivia game on Google assistant to get the physical perks??

For your problem i would suggest to edit your excel and copy link and paste again and then run the stimulator.

Comment: Okay, I'll just give it a shot again! Thanks.